# When doing a shallow git clone, how to limit git blame to the depth of the clone?

Tags: git, git-blame, git-sparse-checkout

I have a short-lived process which does a shallow clone (e.g. `git clone --depth 50 <repo>`) of a huge repo with ancient history.

Part of the process, in some conditions, it uses runs git blame on certain lines of certain files.
In some cases, where the line of the file was last changed in a very early commit of the repo, the git blame command takes a very long time.
I think it lazy-downloads the history again and again until it reaches the old commit.

In my case, if the blame was not part of the shallow clone, I don't care about it.

Is there a way to limit git blame to the already downloaded commits and return an error message (or any other info I can parse) and not lazy-load older commits?

I tried using:

```bash
git blame -L 10,10 <SHA>^50..<SHA> -- file.txt
```

and

```bash
git blame -L 10,10 <SHA>~50..<SHA> -- file.txt
```

but in both cases I sometime get the following error:

```bash
fatal: bad revision
```

**UPDATE**: I failed to mention that I'm also using treeless `--filter=tree:0`

I get the following (repeating) messages in stderr:

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think it lazy-downloads the history again and again until it reaches the old commit.

No, it doesn't. When used with a shallow clone, neither `git blame` nor any other command will "lazy-download" history beyond the shallow horizon (partial cloning with `git clone --filter` is different; objects that were filtered out at clone time *may* be lazy-fetched, because you have a full commit history; it's just missing some of its trees and/or blobs).

The behavior you're asking for is already the way git works. `git blame` in a shallow clone just attributes any changes made before the shallow horizon to the first commit (or to nothing if you use `-b`), and doesn't fetch anything. Whatever is causing your slowness, it's something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

You are correct, I failed to mention I'm also using treeless filter. please see update above.